# How to create this exact grainy effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I am trying to create this exact grainy text effect with the different word, but i am unable to create exact like this one. [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why was it not satisfactory? Ugh, looking more closely, most of that is low-quality jpg noise. Just save as a low quality jpg on a not absolutely flat field… tadahh.

Comment: Are you using Illustrator **or** Photoshop? While they can often both be part of a process, it's helpful to know what you are trying.

Comment: @Scott I am trying photoshop

Comment: I need the same blur and noise, how can we get both?

Comment: You can't get noise and blur at the same time. These are separate operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a bit like Adobe Camera RAW's grain effect, with the roughness and size sliders maxxed out.

To use it, covert your artwork to a Smart Object in Photoshop, and do *Filter > Camera RAW filter*.  Go into the effects, and increase the grain, and max out the size and roughness sliders, or adjust to what you like.

[image]click image to see larger

Also as Tetsujin has commented above, there are excessive jpeg compression artifacts, so if you want that too, then export as a JPEG and decrease the quality slider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bily Kerr, I tried that but didn't get results, here is what i got https://ibb.co/1Q8tXhs

Comment: @David - well it obviously worked, but maybe it's just a bit too much. Adjust the settings until you get the desired result.  Also, there's no blurry grey background as in your original example. This answer is only for the grain, not how to make the artwork!

Comment: Quick 2 minute version - https://i.stack.imgur.com/z84qP.jpg - You need to keep playing with jpg artefacting & blur to get an exact match. I saved this at 1% quality, then re-imported it & added gaussian blur. You probably need quite a specific set of pixel dimensions/resolution too, to get a exact match. [I didn't check that before I started]

Comment: Looks pretty good with the right artwork, just a bit of motion blur under the text. Then applying the grain in adobe camera raw [see example](https://imgur.com/a/iPVA71x). This is really basic stuff TBH.

Comment: Thanks, Billy, I got it. here it is https://ibb.co/sWw6K3J